# How to plot the graph of $[|\sin x|+|\cos x|]$ where [.] is the G.I.F?

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, graphing-functions

I was solving an integral $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}[|\sin x|+|\cos x|]dx$$ and wondered whether i can do the same using graph of the function $$f(x)=[|\sin x|+|\cos x|]$$ where $[.]$ denotes greatest integer function and | | is the mod function.When i did the same using an online graphing calculator all i landed up with was this-
$$|\sin x|+|\cos x| \implies$$

[image: $|\sin x|+|\cos x|$]

$$[|sinx|+|cosx|] \implies$$

[image: $[|sinx|+|cosx|]$]

Can anyone plz help me out by providing a step by step guide for plotting the same by hand.I dont have any idea on how to do the same.Any solution would be apreciated.

Comment: This graph seems incorrect. The values of the greatest integer function are always integers, so the values of $f(x)$ should always be integers.

Comment: The function is constant and its value is 2, thus the integral is $4\pi$

Comment: This is the graph of $|\sin x|+|\cos x|$ without the greatest integer function

Comment: @Raffaele I am not interested in solving the integral value. I just need the graphing process

Comment: You must be aware that max. value of $\sin x + \cos x$ is $\sqrt2$, which after little work means the max value of $|\sin x| + |\cos x|$ is $\sqrt2$ again.

Comment: On the other hand squaring that expression you will get $1 + |\sin 2x|$, which means that its always greater than or equal to 1 too. Hence, the GIF is always one.

Comment: @sawarnik Thnx bhai